# Range-based for with brace-initializer over non-const values?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I am trying to iterate over a number of `std::list`s, sorting each of them. This is the naive approach:

```
#include<list>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
    list<int> a,b,c;
    for(auto& l:{a,b,c}) l.sort();
}
```

producing

```
aa.cpp:5:25: error: no matching member function for call to 'sort'
        for(auto& l:{a,b,c}) l.sort();
                             ~~^~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_list.h:1586:7: note: 
      candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >', but method is not marked const
      sort();
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_list.h:1596:9: note: 
      candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were
      provided
        sort(_StrictWeakOrdering);
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Am I correctly guessing that brace-initializer is creating copy of those lists? And is there a way to not copy them, and make them modifiable inside the loop? (other than making list of pointers to them, which is my current workaround).

Comment: A bit ugly, but perhaps `for (auto l : {&a, &b, &c}) l->sort();`

Comment: @Quentin, and the initializer_list is a list of copies of the original `a`,`b`,`c`. So, even if we could get non-`const` references it wouldn't be very useful. We need an initializer_list (or similar container) which stores references. Which is not possible I think, unless you build your own container (or use one from Boost maybe)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are guessing correctly. `std::initializer_list` elements are always `const` (which makes `sort()`ing them impossible, as `sort()` is a non-`const` member function) and its elements are always copied (which would make `sort()`-ing them meaningless even if they weren't `const`). From [dcl.init.list], emphasis mine:

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation
> allocated a temporary array of N elements of type **const E**, where N is the number of elements in the
> initializer list. Each element of that array is **copy-initialized** with the corresponding element of the initializer
> list, and the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array. *[ Note:* A constructor
> or conversion function selected for the copy shall be accessible (Clause 11) in the context of the initializer
> list. *—end note ]* If a narrowing conversion is required to initialize any of the elements, the program is
> ill-formed. *[ Example:*

```
struct X {
    X(std::initializer_list<double> v);
};
X x{ 1,2,3 };
```

> The initialization will be implemented in a way roughly equivalent to this:

```
const double __a[3] = {double{1}, double{2}, double{3}};
X x(std::initializer_list<double>(__a, __a+3));
```

> assuming that the implementation can construct an `initializer_list` object with a pair of pointers. *—end
> example ]*

There is no way to make them non-const or non-copied. The pointer solution works:

```
for (auto l : {&a, &b, &c}) l->sort();
```

because it's the *pointer* that's const, not the element it's pointing to. The other alternative would be to write a variadic function template:

```
template <typename... Lists>
void sortAll(Lists&&... lists) {
    // before C++17
    using expander = int[];
    expander{0, (void(lists.sort()), 0)...};

    // C++17 or later
    (lists.sort(), ...);
}

sortAll(a, b, c);
```

You could also, I guess, write a helper to wrap your lists into an array of `reference_wrapper` to `list<int>` (since you can't have an array of references), but this is probably more confusing than helpful:

```
template <typename List, typename... Lists>
std::array<std::reference_wrapper<List>, sizeof...(Lists) + 1>
as_array(List& x, Lists&... xs) {
    return {x, xs...}; 
}

for (list<int>& l : as_array(a, b, c)) {  // can't use auto, that deduces
    l.sort();                             // reference_wrapper<list<int>>,
}                                         // so would need l.get().sort()
```

Comment: In the answer it should be made more clear that the compiler error is caused by the implicit `const`, and that the copying of the lists is an additional problem that has nothing to do with the compiler error.

Comment: @vog, in one sense the copying is actually the real problem with this code. In order for the `sort` to apply to the original `a`, `b` and `c` we need (non-`const`) references to the original objects. Perhaps we could say that this is the reason the members are const, to avoid giving the impression that modifying them would be useful.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I fully agree. I'm just saying that the answer should distinguish between the real problem and the problem the compiler complains about, even if those two are related.

Comment: Another solution would be variadic function, that returns array of references, similar to `std::tie`. That could be more generic.

Comment: @Slava, but an array of references isn't possible in C++. But you're right that a more flexible container could be built. (Actually, I'm trying to code something up now!)

Comment: @vog Sure, added a bit.

Comment: @Slava, I've added such an answer here. `for(auto& l : ref_range(a,b,c))`

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to write a function `ref_range` which allows you to do this:

```
for(auto& l : ref_range(a,b,c)) {
    l.sort();
}
```

As others have said, once you write `{a,b,c}` you are stuck with an `initializer_list`, and such a list always takes copies of its arguments. The copies are `const` (hence your error), but even if you could get a non-`const` reference you would be modifying the copies of `a`, `b` and `c` instead of the originals.

Anyway, here is `ref_range`. It builds a `vector` of `reference_wrapper`.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724863/range-based-for-with-brace-initializer-over-non-const-values
#include<list>
#include<functional>
#include<array>

template<typename T, std:: size_t N>
struct hold_array_of_refs {
    using vec_type = std:: array< std:: reference_wrapper<T>, N >;
    vec_type m_v_of_refs;
    hold_array_of_refs(vec_type && v_of_refs) : m_v_of_refs(std::move(v_of_refs)) { }
    ~hold_array_of_refs() { }
    struct iterator {
        typename vec_type :: const_iterator m_it;
        iterator(typename vec_type :: const_iterator it) : m_it(it) {}
        bool operator != (const iterator &other) {
            return this->m_it != other.m_it;
        }
        iterator& operator++() { // prefix
            ++ this->m_it;
            return *this;
        }
        T& operator*() {
            return *m_it;
        }
    };

    iterator begin() const {
        return iterator(m_v_of_refs.begin());
    }
    iterator end() const {
        return iterator(m_v_of_refs.end());
    }
};

template<typename... Ts>
using getFirstTypeOfPack = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;


template<typename ...T>
auto ref_range(T&... args) -> hold_array_of_refs< getFirstTypeOfPack<T...> , sizeof...(args)> {
    return {{{ std:: ref(args)... }}}; // Why does clang prefer three levels of {} ?
}

#include<iostream>
int main(void){
    std:: list<int> a,b,c;
    // print the addresses, so we can verify we're dealing
    // with the same objects
    std:: cout << &a << std:: endl;
    std:: cout << &b << std:: endl;
    std:: cout << &c << std:: endl;
    for(auto& l : ref_range(a,b,c)) {
        std:: cout << &l << std:: endl;
        l.sort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you use `std::vector`? As you know size at compile time `std::array` can be used, or I am missing something?

Comment: Changed to `array`, thanks @Slava. And simplified ref_range a little. But I'm surprised a little at clang, it suggested I add a third set of braces in my return statement from `ref_range`

Comment: Can these be `constexpr` (to enable optimizations such as loop unrolling)?

Comment: @BenVoigt, good suggestion. I'm trying it now, having trouble with the `operator++` though. Even switching on C++14 isn't helping. Will keep trying though

Comment: @BenVoigt, [got it working](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d877937986702cf3) with constexpr. Had to make some changes, including implement my own reference_wrapper. Clang 3.5 works, but not g++ 4.9.3. The g++ 5.2.0 on Coliru works though

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: That's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The `{...}` syntax is actually creating an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). As the linked page states :

> A `std::initializer_list` object is automatically constructed when:
>
> - [...]
> - a *braced-init-list* is bound to `auto`, including in a ranged for loop

And :

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<T>` is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type `const T`.

Thus, you can't modify the objects accessed through this `initialize_list`. Your solutions with the pointers looks like the easiest one to me.

Comment: Elsewhere on this question, you said that the initializer list does not copy its items. But I've checked in this example and the address of the items in the range-based for are different from the addresses of the original `a`,`b`,`c`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid yes, I edited that same comment as I found it just afterwards. "The underlying array is a temporary array, in which each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original initializer list."

Answer (score 2):

Direct answer to your question:

> Am I correctly guessing that brace-initializer is creating copy of
>   those lists?

Yes, this is the first problem. Your code would create copies of your lists, sort those copies, and finally forget the sorted copies.

**However**, that alone would just result in non-working code. The compiler error hints to a second problem: The implicit type of `l` is `list<int> const&`, rather than `list<int>&`. So the compiler complains that `sort()` tries to modify constant lists.

You can work around this second problem with a nasty `const_cast`:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
    list<int> a,b,c;
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(0);
    a.push_back(1);
    for(auto& l:{a,b,c}) const_cast<list<int>&>(l).sort();
    for(auto i:a) cout << i << endl;
}
```

However, that will then trigger the first problem: Your list of lists contains copies, and only those copies are sorted. So the final output is not what you want:

```
2
0
1
```

The easiest workaround is to create a list of pointers to your lists:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
    list<int> a,b,c;
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(0);
    a.push_back(1);
    for(auto l:{&a,&b,&c}) l->sort();
    for(auto i:a) cout << i << endl;
}
```

This will produce the desired result:

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already mentioned `std::reference_wrapper`, but they then used it to create an STL container instead of sticking with the brace-initializer list.

So all you need to do is:

```
for(auto& l:{std::ref(a),std::ref(b),std::ref(c)}) l.get().sort();
```

Of course, this is very similiar to the pointer solution already suggested.