# How to use initializer-list loops for modifying elements?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I can easily simulate a `for .. in` loop using initializer lists for read access

```
std::list<int> foo, bar, baz;

int main() 
{
  foo.push_back(3);
  foo.push_back(2);
  bar.push_back(1);
  for (auto &x : {foo, bar, baz}) {
    // x.push_back(42);
    std::cout << x.size() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
2
1
0
```

What should I do so that I can modify the actual objects, just as in the commented line:

```
// x.push_back(42);
```

Comment: Very closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724863/range-based-for-with-brace-initializer-over-non-const-values

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
for (std::list<int>& x : {std::ref(foo), std::ref(bar), std::ref(baz)}) {
  x.push_back(42);
  std::cout << x.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com).  Where is std::reference_wrapper called out?  I.e.  What is that tool, how does it work, what does it do, etc?

Answer (score 20):

A pointer-based trick that we know from C might be applied as follows

```
  for (auto x : { &foo, &bar, &baz }) {
    x->push_back(42);
    std::cout << x->size() << std::endl;
  }
```

However, this assumes that you actually want to work with the *original* objects, as opposed to their copies. (The code you posted originally actually works with copies.)

Comment: It's a good point! I was pretty sure I'm working with the original objects